# Django + CELERY_TASK_ROUTES not working with module relative path and wildcard

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery, django-celery

Using Celery 4.1.0 with Django 1.11 and Redis as broker, with the following abstract config,

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('my_app.celery_tasks',)  # Can see the list of tasks in the workers log, so the import works.

CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default.#'),
    Queue('my-queue', Exchange('my-queue'), routing_key='my-queue.#'),
)

CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
    # 'my-celery-task': {'queue': "my-queue"},
    'my_app.celery_tasks.*': {'queue': "my-queue"},
}
```

running 2 workers to consume tasks from 'default' and 'my-queue'.

***my-celery-task*** is a named `@task` in `my_app/celery_tasks.py` which is routed to 'my-queue' as expected if I uncomment the first line in `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES`.

But what I need is to route all the tasks defined in `my_app/celery_tasks.py` to 'my-queue'. Following the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing) here, but still the task is routed to the 'default' queue. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Use `CELERY_ROUTES` instead of `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES`.

Comment: they have some differences when converting config names to django settings variable, for more see https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#latentcall-django-admonition